# Powershell one liner to execute grunt task

Tags: powershell

It simply escapes me how to do this elegantly (in PSv1 because it's in a post-build event):  Simply running `powershell -command $path\grunt` should work?  The powershell instance is launched from cmd, hence the 'powershell' in the beginning. I couldn't find the answer anywhere...

Comment: What is the variable `$path` meant to contain? Is `grunt` an exe file?

Comment: nope, just a simple, plain path... I know how to get it to work with some 3 line code... but there has to be an elegant 1-liner solution to this?!

Comment: and no, grunt is no exe file... (that would be too easy)

Comment: Is `$path` a variable or did you just substitute it for an actual literal path? What exactly is `grunt` if it's not an executable? A batch script? If you want us to help with your problem you need to describe the problem in more detail.

Comment: What is the 3 lines that do work?

Comment: sorry, thought that was clear. a node.js script / taskrunner called grunt. it's an expression in powershell terms. The lines that do work are: ``` Select $LiteralPath | where $folder -eq $correctFolder | functionWrapper { grunt }``` The line in bash would just be what my original question was. I really do hope there is a way to just tack on a path to an expression and invoke it in a different directory

Comment: The general question would be: how to add a path to an expression? As I see it there is no simple way to do this? I hope I'm wrong

Comment: Again, do you have a literal path or a variable?

Comment: a literal path (does that matter if it's wrapped in a variable for the question, though?)

Comment: Yes, it does matter, because not only does variable syntax differ between PowerShell and CMD, but `$path` in PowerShell is something entirely different from `%path%` in CMD.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You mean something like this?

```
PowerShell.exe -Command "cd C:\MyPath; grunt"
```

The semicolon is the end-of-statement character.  It's not required like it is in many languages, but PowerShell does have one.

Comment: and again... how could something that easy escape me. Thank you a lot...